# SQL Server 2005 Standard edition on Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2005, installation

Has anyone succeeded in installing SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition on Windows 7 Professional?

When I try this the installation fail in installed Database Services, and I am told to look in the log files. I can't figure out what the problem is from the log files.

Are there anybody else who has experienced something similar ? and if so how did you fix it ?

Best regards Stig Nielsson

Comment: I've been able to install SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition on Windows 7 Ultimate if that's any help.  I seem to remember a warning coming up during the installation about needing to apply SP3 after installing SQL Server but other than that I didn't have any problems.

Comment: I suggest posting the relevant parts of the log files on serverfault.com.

Comment: what is the exact error message you get while installing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in the log files, you can start with this file:

```
  %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Summary.txt
```

If you post any suspicious-looking lines here, we'll have a better guess.  If you can't figure out which line(s) might indicate a problem, then post the whole summary file somewhere so that we can help you figure it out.  Right now, we only know as much as you've told us, which is simply, "it's broke."

Likely culprits:

- conflicting installations of Visual Studio
- previous installations of 2005 (including Express)
- insufficient privileges (are you running the setup program as an administrator?)
- anti-virus / spyware scanners (doubtful, but I'd disable them during setup anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing warning about I have to install SP2 after the installation.
After I installed SP2 and SQL-Server works fine.